# the layoutInflater.inflate() method can't resolve the layoutName

Tags: java, android, layout-inflater

i'm making a custom listView but when make the inflater it can't resolve the "row" layout

```
@Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row , null );
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Check your _R_ import. Do you have _row_ layout?

Comment: row should be view layout for your items inside listview. make sure you have row.xml in your res -> layout -> row.xml.

Comment: Is this file in an another package or folder?

Answer (score 0):

please check your row XML mistake while not get id from R file. pleas check UI file.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have row.xml in following direction!
res -> layout -> row.xml
if you have that file but problem still exists then your R is probably not imported
add this line in your imports:

```
import PACKAGE_NAME.R;
```

while package name can be something like  =>   ir.ark.tourism

also use 
`View row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row , viewGroup,false );
            return row;`

instead of

`View row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row , null );
            return null;`